# How to reset recaptcha on Success for signInWithPhoneNumber()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, invisible-recaptcha

I am using `Firebase.auth()signInWithPhoneNumber(number, appVerifier)`

Everything is working as expected however I am trying to resolve the issue below:
[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new app.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("sendBtn", {
      size: "invisible",
      callback: function () {
        onSend();
      },
    });
  });

  const onSend = (value) => {
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const setMobile = "valid mobile..";
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(setMobile, appVerifier)
      .then(function (confirmationResult) { 
        appVerifier.reset()
        console.log(confirmationResult)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        appVerifier.reset()
        console.log(error);
      }); 
  };
```

How can I correctly handle Recaptcha? Without it being rendered multiple times. I'm looking to destroy it on Recaptcha on success, I have gone through the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) but clear() or reset() does not seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a empty array of dependencies to useEffect to trigger only after initial render, more details in this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481525/10353987).

Additionally it may be a good idea to add an if check to see if `window.recaptchaVerifier` is set (in case you have component using recaptcha anywhere else on your page), before trying to initialize a new `RecaptchaVerifier`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new app.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sendBtn', {
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: function () {
        onSend();
      }
    });
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to unmount the Recaptcha on completion? Just trying to solve a bug

Comment: @Freddy. as I understand the `.clear` function is used for this purpose, but you have to clear the DOM element yourself. The following stackoverflow answer discusses your exact use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51328808/10353987

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the dependencies of your useEffect otherwise it will be executed each time the component render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // recaptcha
}, [])
```